# create exe from visual studio 2012 c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I made a little app with c# which I wanted to send to a friend to get an opinion. Problem is when I selected **release** configuration and click rebuild I get 7 additional files(3 dll's, 1 exes,...) along with the exe I want. Am I doing something wrong? I used to get single .exe files back when I used c++ with VS 2005.

Comment: are any extra ddl referenced in project?

Comment: yes 3 dlls are referenced.

Comment: just zip the release folder to your friend and send them that

Comment: then just copy the main exe & 3 dll, zip them & send it to your friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been an horrible hour. Couldn't get **Clickonce** working for such a simple app. Moving  just the 3 referenced **dlls** and the **exe** to another folder worked. **Wix** on the other hand...is difficult to say the least.

However, **[this](http://www.installsimple.com/download.htm)** allowed me to create a single setup file if not an exe in 10 mins. I sent a shortcut to the desktop which is more or less what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything wrong. Its just that at release additional files are generated like AppConfig.xml for instange that holds your application settings, or a ClickOnce deployment package so that your friend can install the app. To get more used to c# you can start by googling articles about the differences between debug and release

Comment: I'll give clickOnce a go. It sounded like it was for something else with all the security info.

Comment: Good luck, keep in mind that you can also use Windows installer for more advanced deployment scenarios.

Comment: clickOnce was not the thing. I guess it's better for online installation. I'm going to try Windows Installer now.

Comment: @mechanicum What makes you say that? Click Once is intended to be used for publishing to CDs/External Storage as well

Comment: @Jamie Keeling, Agreed, it only asks to download components when they are missing, including the .NET Framework when its not installed.

Comment: I moved the clickOnce Installer to a seperate folder but it first asked for the manifest, then the dlls then asked me to place the dlls in to the Global Assembly Cache and contact my system admin. EDIT: I just tried the clickOnce ınstaller directly from the release folder...same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the Click Once facility built into Visual Studio 2012?

[Click Once Deployment - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/t71a733d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Click Once will generate an installer that will that your friend can execute. It will automatcially download and install any dependencies (such as a specific .NET Runtime) if necessary.

To distribute referenced DLLs look at the following URL as it suggests the correct configuration settings:

[How to: Specify Which Files Are Published by ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/kzy0fky2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: that still wont generate just one single file in the release folder of the project.